# R, Igraph: convert edges to tibble or data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph, tibble

I must be drowning in a cup of tea, but at the same time I have been banging my head against the wall for hours.
Please have a look at the reprex below where I generate an igraph graph object g and I collect the edges stemming from some vertices into an object called dd.
My goal is to convert to convert dd into a dataframe or a tibble but the most obvious methods (as_data_frame and as_tibble) fail completely.
Can anyone help me out?

Many thanks

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     as_data_frame, groups, union
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     compose, simplify
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     crossing
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tibble':
#> 
#>     as_data_frame
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union

g <- make_ring(10)


dd <- E(g)[from(1:4)]

## this does not work

dd%>%as_tibble
#> Error in as.data.frame.default(value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE): cannot coerce class '"igraph.es"' to a data.frame

## neither this

dd%>%as_data_frame
#> Error in as_data_frame(.): Not a graph object

## so what to do?
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: You have provided code with no description of the underlying question and goals.

Comment: I totally disagree. I want to convert the bunch of edges collected into dd to a dataframe or a tibble for further manipulation. Please read the whole post.

Comment: Posting failed code is not generally useful in understanding goal. You should now take the material in you comment and improve the question with SO's [edit] facilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extracted edge identifiers from the graph-object. Now you need to understand how the graphs and edges are represented. So use the `plot` and `str` commands to examine the details of the `g` and `dd` objects:

```
> g <- make_ring(10)
> plot(g)
> dd <- E(g)[from(1:4)]
> dd
+ 5/10 edges from 96250aa:
[1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 1--10
> str(dd)
 'igraph.es' int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 10   # so it's really just a numeric vector
 - attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
 - attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
> help(pack=igraph)
> as_edgelist(g)
      [,1] [,2]     # whereas the original graph (list) converts to two columns
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    2    3
 [3,]    3    4
 [4,]    4    5
 [5,]    5    6
 [6,]    6    7
 [7,]    7    8
 [8,]    8    9
 [9,]    9   10
[10,]    1   10
> as_edgelist(dd)
Error in as_edgelist(dd) : Not a graph object
```

After looking at the results I opened the igraph help index and noted a function named as_ids that was described as: "Convert a vertex or edge sequence to an ordinary vector"

```
> as_ids(dd)
[1]  1  2  3  4 10
> str(g)
List of 10
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 2 10
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 1 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 2 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 3 5
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 4 6
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 5 7
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 6 8
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 7 9
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 8 10
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : 'igraph.vs' int [1:2] 1 9
  .. ..- attr(*, "env")=<weakref> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "graph")= chr "96250aab-d2ab-43aa-882d-6ef695323b0a"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "igraph"
```

So if you wanted a data.frame to hold the edge identifiers, you could get a dataframe with a single column, by just doing:

```
 dd_df <- data.frame( ids <- as_ids(dd) )
```

But if you wanted a two column result that use `as_data_frame` method for graph object and then select the first 4 rows of the graph:

```
> as_data_frame(g)[1:4, ]
  from to
1    1  2
2    2  3
3    3  4
4    4  5
```

Comment: Thanks. The as_data_frame(g)[1:4, ] is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `igraph::as_data_frame` (we need to indicate `igraph::` to see sure that R will not confuse it with `tidyverse::as_data_frame`)

Here is your graph

```
g <- make_ring(10)
g
```

```
IGRAPH 0d30647 U--- 10 10 -- Ring graph
+ attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/l), circular (g/l)
+ edges from 0d30647:
 [1] 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 5-- 6 6-- 7 7-- 8 8-- 9 9--10 1--10
```

Here is how you convert edges to a data frame:

```
g %>%  igraph::as_data_frame()
```

```
   from  to
  <dbl> <dbl>

1   1   2       
2   2   3       
3   3   4       
4   4   5       
5   5   6       
6   6   7       
7   7   8       
8   8   9       
9   9   10      
10  1   10
```